# command in .bashrc file cannot be executed correctly when submitted a pbs job

Tags: bash, shell, module, pbs

I have a script to submit a job in bash shell, which looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
# PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -l walltime=00:30:00
#PBS -N xxxxx
```

However, after I submitted my job, I got an error message in `xxxxx.e8980` file as follows:

```
/home/xxxxx/.bashrc: line 1: /etc/ini.modules: No such file or directory
```

but the file `/etc/ini.modules` is there. Why the system cannot find it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does it exist on the machine the job ends up running on?

Comment: Please do these two commands and report their output:
1.  file /etc/ini.modules
2.  head /etc/ini.modules

Comment: Hi that other guy, The file is not there, I think this probably the reason, Many thanks!

Comment: Hi aqn, I think the reason is when I submitted my file, the local node doesn't have the file ini.modules. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

When referencing files in a job that will be submitted to a cluster, you must either force the job to the specific node(s) that have the file or make sure the file is present on all compute nodes in the cluster.